# How to click on a button text in selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

[These are the buttons I want selenium to click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GmpS.png)

[This is what the elements of the 4 buttons showed above look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQBGS.png)

Want selenium to click on this button with the element below:

```
<div id="book_e43c607b-0fba-472e-ab84-7dd8ff6efb6b" class="time-slot"
 data-slotclub="calgary" data-slotdate="Saturday, 17 July 2021"
 data-slottime="at 5:00 PM">
<div class="time-slot-clock"></div>
<div class="time-slot-box">
    <div class="time-slot-data-line">Saturday, 17 July 2021</div>
    <div class="time-slot-data-line">at 5:00 PM</div>
    <div class="time-slot-data-line">Click to reserve</div>
</div>
```

however, rather than using XPath or class to find the button, I want to see if there's a way to use the  " data-slottime="at 5:00 PM" " portion on the third line in the block above.
I tried using the below code to click the button however element cant be found.

```
time = driver.find_element_by_link_text("at 8:00 AM")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", time)
```

This code however works, but uses the unique x path which i am not interested in:

```
time = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"book_1178d802-ba18-4742-9dce-aac877ad3efb\"]/div[2]/div[1]")  

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", time)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is strongly recommended not to name variables with keyword names.
So calling web element `time` is a bad practice.
Now, if you want to select web element by text it can be done like this:

```
time_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'the_time')]")
```

Also it is not recommended to click elements with JavaScript instead of selenium `.click()` method until you have no alternative.
So I'd use rather this:

```
time_el.click()
```

I guess you will pass the time as a parameter here, in this case it can be something like this:

```
time_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'{0}')]").format(the_time_variable)
time_el.click()
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer! However I still can not get it to work, in the code you suggested I am wondering what would the_time_variable be? I set the_time_variable equal to "at 8:00 AM" but it gives me no such element error.

Comment: Does the element presenting a real, changing time? If yes - you can not select element based of totally unknown string value

Comment: No, the element is on a page that contains many different identical buttons with only the time portion become different. If this won't work how can I go about solving this?

Comment: can you share a link to the page?

Comment: I cant send a link because it requires login to access the page, however, I added some pictures in the post. Please give them a look and try to provide a solution, I really appreciate it :)!

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[data-slottime=text_you_want]").click()
```